# How to make QTextBrowser to have biggest size?

Tags: c++, qt, qscrollarea, qlayout

I have QScrollArea which has QVBoxLayout where I place widgets and one of them is QTextBrowser and I want to make QTextBrowser to have size of its content and to remove its scrollbars. 
I inherited QTextBrowser, changed sizePolicy, hid scrollbars and overrided sizeHint() like this:

```
TextBrowserWidget::TextBrowserWidget(QWidget* parent)
    : QTextBrowser(parent)
{
    setSizePolicy(
        QSizePolicy::Preferred,
        QSizePolicy::Minimum);

    setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
}

QSize TextBrowserWidget::sizeHint() const
{
    if (document()) {
        auto docSize = document()->size();
        return QSize(docSize.width(), docSize.height() + 10);
    } else
        return QTextBrowser::sizeHint();
}
```

But this works with delay, at first widget becomes small and after 1-2 seconds it becomes bigger. 
I am not sure if it's good solution. What is the right way to do it?

Comment: Hiding the bars will not prevent your widget to crop the content, it is not a policy for the size (i.e. it does **not** mean _resize so you don't need scrollbar_). You can remove this, when your widget will have the size you want the scrollbars will be hidden.Why did you change the QSizePolicy ? The default _Expanding_ seems to be what you want. You can take a look at [QAbstractScrollArea::sizeAdjustPolicy](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#sizeAdjustPolicy-prop), maybe this will do what you want without touching to `sizeHint()`.

Comment: @ymoreau, yes, I know about scrollbar policy.
With default size policy widget decreases in size.
And sizeAdjustPolicy also doesn't work

Comment: @ymoreau, I solved it(look down). I am not sure if it's the best solution, but it works pretty cool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TextBrowserWidget::TextBrowserWidget(QWidget* parent)
    : QTextBrowser(parent)
{
    setSizePolicy(
        QSizePolicy::Minimum,
        QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding);

    connect(
        this, &TextBrowserWidget::textChanged,
        this, &TextBrowserWidget::updateSize);

    setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
}

QSize TextBrowserWidget::sizeHint()
{
    updateSize();
    return QTextBrowser::sizeHint();
}

void TextBrowserWidget::updateSize()
{
    document()->setTextWidth(viewport()->size().width());
    auto docSize = document()->size().toSize();

    setMinimumWidth(docSize.width());
    setMinimumHeight(docSize.height() + 10);
}
```